What are the update equations for Double Expected Sarsa with an $\epsilon$-greedy target policy?
This is question 6.13 in Sutton-Barto,page 136.

What are the update equations for Double Expected Sarsa with an $\epsilon$-greedy target policy?

The answer is given as follows:

Let $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ be the two action-value functions and let $\pi_1$
and $\pi_2$ be their $\epsilon$-greedy policies, respectively. Then, the updates would be:


$Q_1(S_t, A_t) \leftarrow Q_1(S_t, A_t)+\alpha\Big[R_{t+1}+\gamma \displaystyle \sum_{a}\pi_2(a|S_{t+1})Q_1(S_{t+1},a)-Q_1(S_t, A_t)\Big] $


$Q_2(S_t, A_t) \leftarrow Q_2(S_t, A_t)+\alpha\Big[R_{t+1}+\gamma \displaystyle \sum_{a}\pi_1(a|S_{t+1})Q_2(S_{t+1},a)-Q_2(S_t, A_t)\Big] $

Could someone explain how they were obtained similar to a reasoning corresponding to double Q-learning?

I thought you had the official answers already? You do know you can get them from the author?

Yes, I have but they just put the equations without any explanation.

Now, I also put the equations  here. What I need is a good explanation on how they were obtained similar to a reasoning for double Q-learning.

That's not how they were obtained though. The two component ideas - double-learning, and expected SARSA - make entirely different changes to the formulation of the update rules, and are compatible. So you simply make both changes: Sum over expected results from policy, and alternate action choice table vs bootstrap estimate table. There's no need to derive these from scratch, and no benefit to doing so at all. In fact I think that defeats the purpose of understanding what is going on - having a feel for these changes as "operators" that modify the equations is more useful and intuitive

What are "action choice table" and "bootstrap estimation table"? Where is the "alternate action choice table vs bootstrap estimate table" in the given updates?

This is a tabular method, so Q(s, a) is a table
